# Django 500 Internal Server Error - ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module:

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-database

Im new to using MySQL in general and as a database for Django. I have followed a number of different tutorials and the documentation but keep getting a **500 Internal Server Error** when i deploy to my production server. It works fine on my development machine.

What am I missing? is there a setting I should change or a step i missed?

Thanks

**The Error logs**

```
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]   File "/var/www/bias_experiment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]   File "/var/www/bias_experiment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]   File "/var/www/bias_experiment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]     __import__(name)
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]   File "/var/www/bias_experiment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
[Mon Aug 18 19:23:10 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

**My Setup**

- Ubuntu VM running 12.04.5 LTS
- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
- Python 2.7.3
- virtualenv==1.7.1.2
- Django==1.6
- MySQL-python==1.2.3
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

**My settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'django_db',                                       
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '', 
    }
}
```

I have created the database on my production environment

```
CREATE DATABASE django_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec) 
mysql>
```

I then ran syncdb

```
(bias_experiment)Macintosh-2:src user$ python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
....
```

Comment: This line `ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)` indicates you might have a version mismatch between MysqlDB and MySQL... have you looked into this?

Comment: On my setup I usually don't provide the host and port.  Have you tried logging into mysql from your server shell?

Comment: @RyanJ You were correct. In my case apt-get was installing MySQL-python==1.2.3 the latest version is MySQL-python==1.2.5. However apt-get would not find this. I had to completely remove MySQL-python==1.2.3 using `sudo apt-get remove --purge python-mysqldb` and then reinstall via pip `sudo pip install mysql-python` (Note the package names are slightly different) If you submit your comment as an answer and include these details I would be happy to accept it. Thanks

Comment: I also restarted apache `sudo service apache2 restart` and restarted mysql `sudo service mysql restart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

indicates you might have a version mismatch between MysqlDB and MySQL.
Sounds like looking in to it and reinstalling your dependent libraries resolved the issue.

**To describe the issue in further detail:**

In this case apt-get was installing MySQL-python==1.2.3. The latest version is MySQL-python==1.2.5. 
However apt-get was not finding it, so completely removing MySQL-python==1.2.3 using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-mysqldb
```

and then reinstall via pip

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

(Note the package names are slightly different)

Comment: on a deployed django project I get the following error in the apache logs: `ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 3, 7, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)`. I am using `mysqlclient==1.3.7`. The project is running through a virtualenv which is passed in the respective wsgi configuration part of the apache.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of helping others who may come to this post with the same error:

I was receiving the same error, but my MySQL-python version was the same as the expected: 1.2.5.  The problem was that I had the MySQLdb folder symlinked into my project's root folder.  By moving the symlinked folder into the folder that holds my Django settings I was able to fix the issue.