# Django Database engine on Google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have some problems by trying to change my database engine on my app engine.

right now i use the "google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms" and it works fine, but it's running slow.

What is the difference in using:

> "google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms" or
>   "django.db.backends.mysql"

i have the following in my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms',
        'INSTANCE': 'xenon-notch-461:madplanuge',
        'NAME': 'madplanuge',
    }
}
```

And when i try to change the database engine to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/xenon-notch-461:madplanuge',
        'NAME': 'madplanuge',
        'USER': 'root',
    }
}
```

I get at server error on my appengine and the logs from the appengine says:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 49, in load_middleware
    mod = import_module(mw_module)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xenon-notch-461/2.382413358316680585/libs/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4)
```

Comment: I think this is due to mysql version. Please try to give mysql version in yaml file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django 500 Internal Server Error - ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370553/django-500-internal-server-error-improperlyconfigured-error-loading-mysqldb-m)

Comment: Im having following in my app.yaml file:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: latest

Answer (score 2):

When to use either module depends on your environment. You can find more details on how to use alternate databases for your working environments in App Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django#development-settings).

Basically, the **django.db.backends.mysql** module enables a Django app running in production to communicate with a production Google Cloud SQL instance.

On the other hand the **google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms** backend is used when running on a developer workstation and accessing a production Cloud SQL instance.

An excerpt from the above mentioned documentation.

> - Use the standard **django.db.backends.mysql** when running in production and accessing a production Google Cloud SQL instance.
> - Use the standard **django.db.backends.mysql** when running on a developer workstation and accessing a local MySQL instance. In this case, the application uses the system MySQLdb driver.
> - Use the custom backend **google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms** when running on a developer workstation and accessing a production Cloud SQL instance.

And yes, the error seems to have something to do with the incorrect version of your MySQLdb module.