# MySQL-python is giving error after installation

Tags: python, mysql-python

pip freeze outputs: MySQL-python==1.2.5 and this is what I need but executing the project results in error:

raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)

Comment: Does `pip freeze` show you other mysql related packages? Otherwise, have you tried to remove and reinstall it again?

Comment: I don't what exact packages it needs but yes I have re-installed it after uninstalling everything again. pip freeze gives output : certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
decorator==4.0.11
Django==1.9
django-cas-client==1.2.0
idna==2.6
kiwisolver==1.0.1
MySQL-python==1.2.5
numpy==1.14.3
pathlib2==2.1.0
pbr==3.0.0
pipenv==11.10.1
psutil==3.4.2
PyMySQL==0.7.9
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2018.4
pyxdg==0.25
requests==2.18.4
six==1.10.0
stevedore==1.21.0
Unidecode==0.4.20
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 500 Internal Server Error - ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370553/django-500-internal-server-error-improperlyconfigured-error-loading-mysqldb-m)